# Is a string in PHP a character array?

Tags: php, c, arrays, string

Like in C, can I use a string as an array?

For example:

```
$a = "abcd";
for ($b = 0; $b <= 3; $b++) {
  echo $a[$b];
}
```

Is a string in PHP an array, or based on arrays as in C?

Comment: Why just not try?

Comment: There's http://www.ideone.com

Comment: Its work but I need to know if string is array?

Comment: No, it's not. It's a string. I just can be (partially) indexed as an array. Be more precise in what you need to know about it. Why is it important?

Comment: Note that strings provide an access syntax similar to arrays `$string[123]` but also provide for `$string{123}` to disambiguate.

Comment: deceze's answer here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193597/strings-as-arrays-in-php) have more info

Comment: in PHP, strings are basically byte arrays. so if your string is only 1 emoji and you try to get its length with strlen, it will return 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually yes, but you have to use another syntax:

```
$a = "abcd";
for ($b = 0; $b <= 3; $b++) {
  echo $a{$b};
}
```

Comment: `echo $a[$b];` works too ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the whole string by checking on the string length, and getting each letter by using the **substr()** function:

```
$a = "abcd";
for($b = 0; $b <= strlen($a); $b++){
    echo substr($a, $b, 1).'<br>';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  $str = "Lorem ipsum";
  if (is_array($str)) {
    echo "$str is array";
  }
  else {
    echo "$str is not array";
  }
?>
```

Result:

Lorem ipsum is not array

so....

Comment: So how its work I mean in C I know that its save in memory like array

Comment: An Array is collection of elements of similar type which are referred by a common name.Each element is accessed by its value. First element has index 0 and last element has index which is 1 less than the size of array. Declaration of Array:- data_type array_name[size]; String is collection of characters. So it is called character array. Each string is terminated by null character('')

Comment: so actual, yes, string located in memory like array, but it is not php array, it is isolated case of php array!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `str_split($string)` in order to convert a string to an array

For instance:

```
var_dump(str_split("abc"));
```

will translate into

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(1) "a"
  [1]=> string(1) "b"
  [2]=> string(1) "c"
}
```