# PHP String Index $str["test"] same as $str[0]?

Tags: php, string, indexing

When referring to an element inside a PHP string like an array, using square brackets [ ] you can use a number like [2] to select a specific character from the string. However, when using a string index like ["example"], it always returns the same result as [0].

```
<?php
$str="Hello world.";
echo $str; // Echos "Hello world." as expected.
echo $str[2]; // Echos "l" as expected.
echo $str["example"]; // Echos "H", not expected.

$arr=array();
$arr["key"]="Test."
echo $arr["key"]; // Echos "Test." as expected.
echo $arr["invalid"]; // Gives an "undefined index" error as expected.
echo $arr["key"];
```

Why does it return the same result as [0]?

Comment: `$str["example"]` returns 0 from `$str = "Hello world."` which makes it return the first letter "H"

Comment: See here why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193597/strings-as-arrays-in-php

Comment: `$str["example"]` = `$str["0"] because of example` and hense h is recieved

Comment: Note that this produces a warning, which indicates it's not something you should ever be actually doing: https://3v4l.org/Dn4uR

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I think my main problem here was that I just forgot typecasting a string to an integer results in 0 if no valid number is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP uses type juggling to convert variables of a non fitting type to a fitting one. In your case, PHP expects your index to be a numeric, an integer to be exact. If you give it a string, it will try to parse it as a number. If not possible, it defaults to zero.

Sidenote: If you give it a string like "9penguins", you will get a 9.

PHP Manual on type juggling: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Nitpick: It's *always* "possible" to cast a string to a number. The result may simply be `0` if no other useful number was found in the string. → http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion