# PHP FETCH data from db on row by row not column

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I need to fetch data from my db. I've done it but when I say fetch array [1], the output is the all second letters in all rows. Here is the code:

```
include "baglan2.php";

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM diziler", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( $query->rowCount() ){
 foreach( $query as $row ){
    echo ($row['link']. "<br />");
 }
```

I tried it with msqli but saw the same result; here is the mysqli code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($baglanti, "SELECT * FROM diziler");
if ( mysqli_affected_rows($baglanti) ){
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ){
       print $row['link'][1]."<br />";
 }
 }
```

For instance all my data are links. When I run print `$row['link'][1]`, it gives "t" letter from "http:" in all rows. I need to fetch my data by row not column. I have tried every method possible. However I couldn't find any method that worked.

for instance I want to make this codes output `"http://**.com"` in each element.

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($baglanti, "SELECT link FROM diziler");
$link_array = array();
if ( $query){
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ){
  $link_array[] =  $row['link'];
 }
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($link_array);`

Comment: `$row['link']` is a string. When you put an index after a string, it accesses that character in the string. Why did you write `[1]`?

Comment: @MartavisGriffin Why shouldn't he use `foreach`? `PDOStatement` implements `Iterable`, which allows you to use `foreach`.

Comment: The first one should have worked, since it doesn't have `[1]` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving solution based on second attempt:-

```
$query = mysqli_query($baglanti, "SELECT link FROM diziler"); 
$link_array = array(); 
if ( $query){ 
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ){ 
               $link_array[] = $row['link']; 
    } 
} 
echo "<pre/>";print_r($link_array); // it have all the links
```

Reason:-  https://eval.in/649070

It's specification is given here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17193651/4248328

That is:- `$string[int]` is syntactic sugar for `substr($string, int, 1)`

Comment: god save u bro :)

Comment: Thanks  @TarıkBaysal.