# A letter contained in a string value in an array is replaced by the value of a variable with that letter's name

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, replace

I have an array:

```
$path_r = array("/oldsites/web-sites","/oldsites/web_elements","/oldsites/web_old_stuff");
```

I do a bunch of stuff to it and everything is fine until this line of code:

```
$path_r[$i][$j] = $name;
```

Just prior to that line, the array ($path_r) looks like this (same as above):

```
Array
(
    [0] => /oldsites/web-sites
    [1] => /oldsites/web_elements
    [2] => /oldsites/web_old_stuff
)
```

But, just after, it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /olds0tes/web-sites
    [1] => /oldsites/web_elements
    [2] => /oldsites/web_old_stuff
)
```

That is to say, the letter "i" in the first value is replaced by the value (zero) of the variable $i. But only once. Can't figure out why. Am I doing something wrong or is it just run-of-the-mill demonic activity?

Comment: What are the values of the other variables?

Comment: what is there in `$name` and `$j`? explanation is when you write `$path_r[$i][$j] ` it's become `"/oldsites/web-sites"[$j]` (if `$i = 0`), and this exactly means `substr($string, int, $j)` so basically `$path_r[$i][$j] = $name;` is mean that assign `$name` at the place of `$path_r[$i][$j]` which is actually `substr($string, int, $j)`

Comment: shawnt00 $i and $j are just incremented $i++ , $j++

Comment: Anant Sorry, I'm not sure I understand.$name is just the name of the next dirname in the path, for example, "/logos". So $path_r[$i][$j] would be Array ( [0] => /oldsites/web-sites [1] => Array ( [0] => logos))

edit: ok, I see what you are saying.  You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @CWill  i mean to say something like this:- https://eval.in/653580   happens in your code. it's quite possible because you said `I do a bunch of stuff to it and everything is fine until this line of code:`. Not exactly like my code link, but something similar like that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said *`"I do a bunch of stuff to it and everything is fine until this line of code:"`*, so we don't know what's going on there in your code.

**One logical explanation why this happens is given below:-**

When you write:-

*`$path_r[$i][$j]`*

it's become something like :- *`"/oldsites/web-sites"[$j]` (if `$i = 0; // for an example`),*

and this expression exactly means *`substr($string, int, $j)`*

(based on this link explanation:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17193651/4248328)

So basically *`$path_r[$i][$j] = $name;`*

is mean that assign *`$name`* at the place of *`$path_r[$i][$j]`* which is actually *`substr($string, int, $j)`*

To understand it easily, check this link:- https://eval.in/653580

**Conclusion:-**

Something like above happens in your code. Not exactly as above, but something similar like that one.