# Displaying proper element from foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to echo one element of the array like `sum1`. But I only get one letter like `s`. Please solve this problem.

```
$nums = array("sum1", 100, 200);
foreach ($nums as $value) {
    echo $value[0];
    echo $value[1];
}
```

Comment: Please describe your script so i can get more idea

Comment: @Klab use in_array('sum1',$nums);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *just* echo 1 item from that array, you should to it like this:

```
echo $nums[0];
```

If you want to loop through all of them, and show each, do it like so:

```
$nums = array("sum1", 100, 200);
foreach ($nums as $value) {
     echo $value."<br>";
}
```

---

### What you did wrong

You had already looped through the array, so you had a `string`. You *can* select the first letter from a string like in this example:

```
$string = "A string";

echo $string[0];
```

Will return `A`, as it's the first index of that string. That is essentially what you did in your loop.

You made your `String` an array, and it showed the index's you selected to be shown.  You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193597/strings-as-arrays-in-php) where the questions asks how to do this. I hope this gives some more clearity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every element of array,
then,

For your array,

```
$nums = array("sum1", 100, 200);
$nums[0] will be sum1
$nums[1] will be 100 
$nums[2] will be 200,
```

Now your loop,

```
foreach ($nums as $value) {
   // here echo $value values are like 'sum1', 100, 200 will be printed.
   // by default string will be considered as array,
   // if you print $value[0], $value[1], $value[2], $value[3] for sum1, it will return, s, u, m, 1 respectively.
  // and integers will be considered as pure value, which you will get in $value only, not in $value[0], ....
}
```

I hope I explained your concern.

Thanks.