# PHP detect variable length string contains any character other than 1

Tags: php, string

Using PHP I sometimes have strings that look like the following:

- 111
- 110
- 011
- 1111
- 0110012

What is the most efficient way (preferably without regex) to determine if a string contains *any* character *other* then the character `1`?

Comment: Loop through the characters.  Set a boolean flag if you find a "1".

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I would probably just use a regex like this: `^1+$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-line code solution that can be put into a conditional etc.:

```
strlen(str_replace('1','',$mystring))==0
```

It strips out the "1"s and sees if there's anything left.

User [Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734189/dont-panic) commented that `str_replace` could be replaced by `trim`:

```
strlen(trim($mystring, '1'))==0
```

which removes leading and trailing 1s and sees if there's anything left. This would work for the particular case in OP's request but the first option will also tell you *how many* non-"1" characters you have (if that information matters).  Depending on implementation, `trim` might run slightly faster because PHP doesn't have to check any characters between the first and last non-"1" characters.

---

You could also [use a string like a character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289203/is-a-string-in-php-a-character-array) and iterate through from the beginning until you find a character which is not `=='1'` (in which case, return true) or reach the end of the array (in which case, return false).

---

Finally, though OP here said "preferably without regex," others open to [regexes](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) might use one:

```
 preg_match("/[^1]/", $mystring)==1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
if (base_convert($string, 2, 2) === $string) {
    // $string has only 0 and 1 characters.
}
```

since your `$string` is basically a binary number, you can check it with `base_convert`.

How it works:

```
var_dump(base_convert('110', 2, 2)); // 110
var_dump(base_convert('11503', 2, 2)); // 110
var_dump(base_convert('9111111111111111111110009', 2, 2)); // 11111111111111111111000
```

If the returned value of `base_convert` is different from the input, there're something other characters, beside `0` and `1`.

If you want checks if the string has **only** `1` characters:

```
if(array_sum(str_split($string)) === strlen($string)) {
    // $string has only 1 characters.
}
```

You retrieve all the single numbers with `str_split`, and sum them with `array_sum`. If the result isn't the same as the length of the string, then you've other number in the string beside `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is treat string like array of symbols and check for something that is not `1`. If it is - break `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($mystring); $i++) {
   if ($mystring[$i] != '1') {
       echo 'FOUND!';
       break;
   }
}
```